# Find and remove all empty files

Tags: unix

How can I search all empty files of non-root system and delete them?

Comment: Saying "Unix" is very vague. There are many unix-like OSs. You should specify the actual OS.

Answer (score 21):

```
find /path/to/mountpoint -empty -type f -delete
```

If your find does not have `-delete` option, replace it with `-exec rm '{}' ';'`

If you want to delete all empty files except for files directly under `/` run:

```
find / -mindepth 2 -empty -type f -delete
```

If you want to delete all empty files, but skip whole `/root` directory run

```
find / \( -path /root -prune \) -empty -type f -delete
```

Comment: i want to say that / includes many directories between them there is the root ,so i want to  execute a find command on all the empty  files on / except those on the root directory ?

Comment: You mean you want to skip `/root` from cleaning? If so, I modified my answer. If not so, please give an example.

Answer (score 4):

`find . -size 0 -print`.

replace `-print` with `-delete` and `.` with the directory you need, but execute carefully, it will *really* delete all empty files.

Comment: thanks, but i want to remove also all empty files of non root directory ,and not in a specific directory ?

Comment: how can i execute that command on all the files except those on the root directory ?

Comment: @maalem: you can specify multiple directories instead of `.`. They can a result of another `find`, not sure how to specify the depth to find dirs in the root dir only (have no chance to test now, try `man find`).

Comment: @maalem, @khachik, i modify the answer to reflect your comments here (if i understood your intent correctly...)